# how to create userdefined serializable class without implementing the serializable interface?

Tags: java, class, serialization

class Siva implements Serializable
{

}

But without using the Serializable interface how to make our class as serializable

Answer (score 1):

Probably if you require to have your own logic for Serialization, then go and implement Externalizable interface.

Answer (score 0):

If can decide not to use Serializable, but then you will have to provide the Serialization/Deserialization logic.

The only way to use the Java API serialization methods is through the Serializable interface.

Just out of curiosity: why don't you want Serializable? It is not that it is hard to implement...